# How to extract with regexp in ansible numbers from hostname without one specific

Tags: regex, ansible

How I can extract with regexp from hostname number without one from domain. Examples:

```
nginx-node-01.prd1.com
nginx-node-10.prd1.com
```

And I need extract only number after nginx-node-, without number from "prd".

When I do this regexp

```
{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('[^0-9]') }}
```

I get output like this

```
011
101
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these strings look very well-structured, you may leverage that and simply remove all chars from the beginning till the first digit with `^\D+` pattern and all chars till the end of string from the first dot using `\..*` pattern, combined with the `|` alternation operator:

```
{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^\\D+|\\..*', '') }}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y4KuSC/1/).

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of string
- `\D+` - one or more chars other than a digit
- `|` - or
- `\.` - a dot
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing all non digits, you can match the format of the string and capture the digits in a group, and use that group in the replacement.

```
^\w+(?:-\w+)+-(\d+)\.\S+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:-\w+)+` Repeat 1+ times a `-` and 1+ word characters
- `-(\d+)` Match `-` and capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `\.\S+` match 1 . and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U8LE5g/1)

Output

```
01
10
```

For example

```
{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^\\w+(?:-\\w+)+-(\\d+)\\.\\S+$', '\\1') }}
```

---

Another option might be regex_search and match 1+ digits between `-` and `.` using lookarounds.

```
(?<=-)\\d+(?=\\.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hs7zh5/1)

Comment: Thanks for help but Ansible gives me a error: Syntax Error while loading YAML- found unknown escape character. 

- { var: "serverNumber: ", value: "{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^\w+(?:-\w+)+-(\d+)\.\S+$', '\\1') }}"}

Comment: @hock Try it like this `regex_replace('^\\w+(?:-\\w+)+-(\\d+)\\.\\S+$', '\\1')`